# UIActivityIndicator - start animating with delay

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiactivityindicatorview

I am making an application which loads data from the web.

It usually takes up 0.5-1 seconds to load the data.

I do use `UIActivityIndicator` to show the user that the data is being loaded.

---

Now the problem is that it's a bit annoying that even if it takes only 0.5-1 seconds to load, the indicator starts immediately.

Is there a way to start the animation with a 2 seconds delay only: and if the loading has finished before that then don't even start it.

> Currently I'm doing this:

```
func loadUserDetails(){

    var shouldStartActivityIndicator : Bool = true
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2.0) {
        if shouldStartActivityIndicator {
            self.tableViewActivityIndicator.startAnimating()
        }
    }

    DispatchQueue.global().async {

        if GlobalSemaphores.shared.userDetails_semaphore.wait(timeout: .now()) == .timedOut { return }

        DispatchQueue.main.async {

            UserDetailsFunctions.shared.loadUserDetails(uId: self.userId) { response, userDetails in
                DispatchQueue.main.async {

                    // DO SOMETHING WITH THE DATA
                    // REMOVED THE LINES

                    self.tableViewActivityIndicator.stopAnimating()
                    shouldStartActivityIndicator = false

                    GlobalSemaphores.shared.userDetails_semaphore.signal()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But this is ugly and I have to rewrite everywhere..

Is there a one-line solution to this? Extension?

**EDIT:**

For example a class like this? Sadly this won't work..

> EXC_BAD_ACCESS

```
class CustomActivityIndicatorView : UIActivityIndicatorView {

    var shouldStartActivityIndicator : Bool = false
    override func startAnimating() {
        shouldStartActivityIndicator = true
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2.0) {
            if self.shouldStartActivityIndicator {
                self.startAnimating()
            }
        }

    }
    override func stopAnimating() {
        shouldStartActivityIndicator = false
        self.stopAnimating()
    }
}
```

Comment: That seems like a suitable solution. If your code is a bit too long, just separate it into multiple functions.

Comment: Your code is almost right, but you need to call `super.startAnimating()` - calling `self.startAnimating()` just calls your own function recursively until the stack explodes

Answer (score 0):

Oh, so I can't override the `startAnimating()` `stopAnimating()` functions, but making an own func does it..

```
class CustomActivityIndicatorView : UIActivityIndicatorView {

    var shouldStartActivityIndicator : Bool = false
    func startAnimatingWithDelay () {
        shouldStartActivityIndicator = true
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1.0) {
            if self.shouldStartActivityIndicator {
                self.startAnimating()
            }
        }

    }
    func stopAnimatingWithDelay() {
        shouldStartActivityIndicator = false
        self.stopAnimating()

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can certainly use a custom subclass of `UIActivityIndicatorView`.  Rather than use `asyncAfter`, which isn't cancellable, I would use a `Timer`:

```
class DelayedActivityIndicatorView: UIActivityIndicatorView {

    var delay: TimeInterval = 2.0   
    private var delayTimer: Timer?

    override func startAnimating() {
        guard self.delayTimer == nil else {
            return // Return if there is already a timer running
        }

        self.delayTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: delay, repeats: false, block: { _ in
            self.delayTimer = nil
            super.startAnimating()
        })

    }

    override func stopAnimating() {
        self.delayTimer?.invalidate()
        self.delayTimer = nil
        super.stopAnimating()
    }

}
```

You had a critical error in your attempt; your overridden function called `self.startAnimating` which means that your function called itself with infinite recursion until it blew up the stack and crashed. What you need is `super.startAnimating` to call the original function, not your override.

Answer (score 0):

Simpliest solution:

```
self.activityIndicator.alpha = 0;
[UIView animateWithDuration:0 delay:2 options:0 animations:^{
    self.activityIndicator.alpha = 1;
} completion:nil];
[self.activityIndicator startAnimating];
```

If got response less than 2 seconds, then activity indicator becomes hidden and returning alpha to 1 changes nothing.